# How can I download Ubuntu packages and take them home for installing?

Tags: downloads

I do not have internet at home but I can go to an internet cafe to download things.

The thing is I have Ubuntu and I don't no how to download Ubuntu-compatible software  from another PC and then get it installed on my PC at home.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading and installing offline packages is a tedious task on ubuntu.
But if you have no other options here is what you do.

1. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/
2. Go to "Search Package Directories" -> Type the name of your package(software) -> Select you Ubuntu version -> click search.
   If your package matches in multiple search results you will be redirected to a page to select from a list of search results. For example if you search "git" for trusty you will get this -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all.
3. Now select the link by the name of your package. Download the package by clicking on the architecture of your Ubuntu version( 32bit ie i386 else 64bit ie amd64).
4. Now install by double-clicking the .deb file.
5. If you are lucky enough(very rarely) you will get your software installed. Otherwise the installation will fail by saying "dependencies are not satisfiable". This means your package depends on some other package and you need to install that dependency package first.
6. Thankfully you get all the links to the dependency packages on the download page of you package with red bullets (mentioned in step.3.)

OR

If you can somehow get another PC with Ubuntu connected to Internet, your life is a bit easy. If you install a software from Software Center they are downloaded to /var/cache/apt/archives. You can just copy them to your Ubuntu PC say on your Desktop -> Open Terminal -> Do the following ->

$ cd ~/Desktop/
 $ sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: Thanks @Rishav i aws downloading usbprog and it is showing dependencies problems. Can u say the procedure to do it. thankyou for the step by step answer.

Comment: It is hard to guess the state of dependencies in your system. If you issue command $sudo apt-get install usbprog. what are the packages listed for installation ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to download the .deb packages from the providers of the software and place it on a thumb drive.  Most (if not all) providers of Ubuntu software will provide the .deb packages somewhere on their site, it's just not always easy to find.

Be sure to download the right .deb for your system, x86 for 32 bit and x64 for 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the software you want to install, can you give an example?
For a lot of software there are .deb packages avalible.
Download them and install them at home with: `sudo dpkg --install *.deb`

Comment: so i need to download a .deb file from the internet and then use the above command. Ok, but how will the computer know that the .deb file is in my pendrive. @Pabi

Comment: In the above command you have to replace `*.deb` with the path to the downloaded .deb file. e.g. /media/external/program.deb

Comment: Hey can u mention any sites to download .deb file @Pabi

Comment: Just google for the program you want. Most developers provide them on there sites.